# Outlook does not connect to my pst file “Error 0×80070718”?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, network-shares

I am running MS Outlook 2010 and this morning I get an unknown exception: ***"Error 0×80070718"***. Outlook has decided that it will not connect to the pst file residing on a network drive.

I've googled a bit to find that such problems may be solved using the "Inbox Repair tool" - wonderful I thougt, it will solved in a couple of seconds.

The thing is that even the Inbox Repair tool, once I try to analize the pst file, thrown an awkward ***"Unknown error 80040116"*** and exits...

Google did not suggest a tool to analize the analize tool :( so I revert to asking real humans, Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are talking about a network storage location, it may be just `disk quota` (check if you are not getting close to the upper limit on that network drive), if you've googled you had probably seen quite a number of questions regarding quota management, albeit not Outlook question, it can be the answer. In such a case you will get unexpected (by outlook) errors like yours.

It's true, it would be nice if MS were smart enough to insert those checks to the PST connect process, but hey, Office is only around so many years... perhaps it has been added in Office 2013, have not checked.

Comment: Yes! that's it. it turns out that even though I had 350MB free space there, still the PST was close to 1GB and perhaps Outlook and the Inbox Repair Tool require 2 times the PST file of free space ... anyway, cleared some room and it's working again.

Comment: SCANPST.exe definitely makes a copy and attempts repairs on the copy (filename.bak).

Comment: @blaughw, tnx for the info. From the fact that OL didn't work, it turns out that OL is probably doing something similar for it's regular work